# Why values of array cannot be printed using foreach loop in called function when array is passed as argument in caller function?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

I am trying to print values of array in called function using foreach loop but facing compilation error. Using c++11 compiler in linux platform and using VIM editor.

Tried using C-style for loop and it worked, when the size is passed from calling function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void call(int [], int);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    call(arr,size);
}

void call(int a[],int size)
{    
    for(int i =0 ; i<size; i++)
        cout << a[i];
}
```

For-each loop used in the below code, which fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void call(int []);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    call(arr);
}

void call(int a[])
{
    for ( int x : a ) 
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

For-each loop in C++11 expects to know the size of array to iterate ? If so, how it will be helpful with respect to traditional for loop. Or something wrong i coded here?

I would look forward for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure someone will come with a suitable duplicate sooner or later. Until then, when used as an argument `int a[]` will be treated as `int* a`, and passing the array will make it *decay* to a pointer to its first element (i.e. you pass `&arr[0]`). That is, all you have is a pointer to the first element.

Comment: `std::vector` is your go to for these kinds of things.  You may consider `std::array`.  What you probably do not want is a C-style array, since it doesn't provide the nice things that you get with C++ such as supporting C++ for-each loop.

Comment: Thanks Ejay, my question was specific to for-each loop in c++11.

Answer (score 5):

Because `int a[]` as function parameter is not an array, it is the same as writing `int *a`.

You can pass the array by reference to make it work:

```
template <size_t N> void call(int (&a)[N])
```

working example: https://ideone.com/ZlEMHC

```
template <size_t N> void call(int (&a)[N])
{
    for ( int x : a ) 
        cout << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    call(arr);
}
```